# Xamarin.Forms - Adding dynamic rows and columns in grid

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have just started learning Xamarin.Forms. I am trying to add rows and columns to a gridview dynamically. I have added code and while executing it, i face the below problem

Problem:

1. UI is empty. I could not see any grid.
   Note: While debugging the code, the breakpoint hits the function where the rows and columns are added.
   But still the UI is empty. I am not sure what may be the problem here.

Can somebody help me

In App.xaml.cs i have added the below code

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public MainPage mainPage;
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            mainPage = new MainPage();
            
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            mainPage.AddRowsAndColumns(1, 17);
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {

        }
    }
```

In MainPage.xaml, i have added an element for Grid

```
    <Grid x:Name="sampleGrid" Margin="30, 30, 30, 30" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">       
    </Grid>
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs, i have added the below code in the function

```
public void AddRowsAndColumns(int rows, int columns)
  {
       for(int index = 0; index <= columns; index++)
        {
           this.sampleGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        }

       for (int index = 0; index < rows; index++)
        {
           this.sampleGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        }

       for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columns; columnIndex++)
        {
           var label = new Label
             {
                Text = "Hello" + columnIndex.ToString(),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
             };
           sampleGrid.Children.Add(label, columnIndex, 0);
        }
   }
```

Comment: you are creating an instance of `MainPage` but you are not assigning it to App's MainPage property, so the UI is never presented to the user

Comment: Try to add `MainPage = mainPage;` below  `mainPage = new MainPage();`.

Comment: assigning the instance to App's mainpage property solved the problem. Thank you